# SVN in Mac OS - unable to open ra_local session, url contains unsupported hostname issue

Tags: macos, svn, tigris

I want to checkout files from an SVN repository which is installed in a windows machine. My system is Mac OS X.. I have installed tigris scPlugin and used the following repository URLs

Repository URL - file://windowsSystemName/Svn_Server/trunk/projectName
ERROR - Unable to open an ra_local session to URL

Local URL 'file://windowsSystemName/Svn_Server/trunk/projectName' contains unsupported hostname

---

I have tried adding a third "/" to the URL and got another error

Repository URL - file:///windowsSystemName/Svn_Server/trunk/projectName

ERROR: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL

Unable to open repository 'file://windowsSystemName/Svn_Server/trunk/projectName'

How can i solve this issue?

Note: Mac OS and SVN are new to me and my knowledge of them is limited.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the error "svn: E170000: Local URL 'file://svnrepos/callsharing' contains unsupported hostname" when attempting to checkout a new repository to a local folder. This happens immediately after creating the repository for the first time, when there have been no commits to the repository yet. The solution that has worked for me is to perform an "svn import" to commit at least once prior to attempting to checkout the repository.

If you have never checked in any files/folders to your repository, simply create a folder to start off the repository, import it, then checkout:

```
$ mkdir ~/emptyproject
$ mkdir ~/emptyproject/branch
$ mkdir ~/emptyproject/tag
$ mkdir ~/emptyproject/trunk
$ svn import ~/emptyproject file:///svnrepos/projectname -m "Initial import"
$ svn checkout file:///svnrepos/projectname /path/to/projectname
```

Obviously, this solution is only intended for a newly created repository, which has never had any files/folders checked in.